# How to get the total number of records till the current hour from a lookup table

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a DataFrame with the lookup table data, for each and every hour there will a entry in this table. How do i calculate the total number of records till the current hour?

**For example my DF data**

```
+----+-----+
|hour|count|
+----+-----+
|0.00|   10|
|1.00|    5|
|2.00|   10|
|3.00|   15|
|4.00|   10|
|5.00|   10|
+----+-----+
```

If i pass "4.00" as input, it should return the total count till 4 hour.

**Expected output is:**

```
Total count
50
```

**Sample code i tried:**

```
    val df = Seq(("0.00", "10"),
          ("1.00", "15")).toDF("hour", "reccount")
        df.show
        df.printSchema

        df.registerTempTable("erv")
        //sqlContext.sql("select hour,reccount from erv").show
sqlContext.sql("select sum(reccount) over(partition by hour) as running_total from erv").show
```

But i am getting the below error.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [1.26] failure:
>   ``union'' expected but `(' found
>
> select sum(reccount) over(partition by hour) as running_total from erv

I also tried the Window functions like below, but Its expecting HiveContext needs to be created, when i try to create HiveContext locally its not creating HiveContext.

**window function code:**

```
val wSpec = Window.partitionBy("hour").orderBy("hour").rowsBetween(Long.MinValue, 0)
df.withColumn("cumSum", sum(df("reccount")).over(wSpec)).show()
```

Comment: @Shankar: The above approach you have used, what about this query.. `select sum(reccount) from erv where hour <= 4`

Comment: @RamPrasadG: Thanks, this one is working..

Comment: Okay.One Tip.. Whenever you are dealing with this kind of.. you can first translate in to sql and then convert using dataframe approach. that will surely work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you'd want to use Window Functions if you can simply `filter`  to get the right hours and `agg`:

```
val upTo = 4.0
val result = input.filter($"hour" <= upTo).agg(sum($"count") as "Total Count")

result.show()
// +-----------+
// |Total Count|
// +-----------+
// |         50|
// +-----------+
```